# Jquery Multi-Step Form

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I have this piece of Jquery and HTML code I found online that creates a multi step form. However, I'd like to be able to manipulate the code so that a user can jump to a specific step.

For example: At the top of the form I pose a question that states, "Do you like Math or Science". The form contains two buttons one that says "Math" and the other "Science". Currently, If you click either button it leads you to the next step of the form. However, I'd like to make it so that if the User clicks "Math" it would go to a different form than if the User clicks "Science".

Here is what the code looks like and you can see the demo @: http://thecodeplayer.com/walkthrough/jquery-multi-step-form-with-progress-bar

```
<!-- multistep form -->
<form id="msform">

    <fieldset>
        <h2 class="fs-title"> Do you enjoy Math or Science?</h2>
        <h3 class="fs-subtitle">This is step 1</h3>

        <input type="button" name="next" class="next action-button" value="Math" /> </li>

        <input type="button" name="next" class="next action-button" value="Science" /> </li>

    </fieldset>

    <fieldset>
        <h2 class="fs-title">Math</h2>
        <h3 class="fs-subtitle">Your presence on the social network</h3>
        <input type="text" name="twitter" placeholder="Twitter" />
        <input type="text" name="facebook" placeholder="Facebook" />
        <input type="text" name="gplus" placeholder="Google Plus" />
        <input type="button" name="previous" class="previous action-button" value="Previous" />
        <input type="button" name="next" class="next action-button" value="Next" />
    </fieldset>


    <fieldset>
        <h2 class="fs-title">Science</h2>
        <h3 class="fs-subtitle">We will never sell it</h3>
        <input type="text" name="fname" placeholder="First Name" />
        <input type="text" name="lname" placeholder="Last Name" />
        <input type="text" name="phone" placeholder="Phone" />
        <textarea name="address" placeholder="Address"></textarea>
        <input type="button" name="previous" class="previous action-button" value="Previous" />
        <input type="button" name="next" class="next action-button" value="Next" />
    </fieldset>

    <fieldset>
        <h2 class="fs-title">Personal Details</h2>
        <h3 class="fs-subtitle">We will never sell it</h3>
        <input type="text" name="fname" placeholder="First Name" />
        <input type="text" name="lname" placeholder="Last Name" />
        <input type="text" name="phone" placeholder="Phone" />
        <textarea name="address" placeholder="Address"></textarea>
        <input type="button" name="previous" class="previous action-button" value="Previous" />
        <input type="submit" name="submit" class="submit action-button" value="Submit" />
    </fieldset>

</form>

<script>
//jQuery time
var current_fs, next_fs, previous_fs; //fieldsets
var left, opacity, scale; //fieldset properties which we will animate
var animating; //flag to prevent quick multi-click glitches

$(".next").click(function(){
    if(animating) return false;
    animating = true;

    current_fs = $(this).parent();
    next_fs = $(this).parent().next();

    //activate next step on progressbar using the index of next_fs
    $("#progressbar li").eq($("fieldset").index(next_fs)).addClass("active");

    //show the next fieldset
    next_fs.show(); 
    //hide the current fieldset with style
    current_fs.animate({opacity: 0}, {
        step: function(now, mx) {
            //as the opacity of current_fs reduces to 0 - stored in "now"
            //1. scale current_fs down to 80%
            scale = 1 - (1 - now) * 0.2;
            //2. bring next_fs from the right(50%)
            left = (now * 50)+"%";
            //3. increase opacity of next_fs to 1 as it moves in
            opacity = 1 - now;
            current_fs.css({'transform': 'scale('+scale+')'});
            next_fs.css({'left': left, 'opacity': opacity});
        }, 
        duration: 800, 
        complete: function(){
            current_fs.hide();
            animating = false;
        }, 
        //this comes from the custom easing plugin
        easing: 'easeInOutBack'
    });
});

$(".previous").click(function(){
    if(animating) return false;
    animating = true;

    current_fs = $(this).parent();
    previous_fs = $(this).parent().prev();

    //de-activate current step on progressbar
    $("#progressbar li").eq($("fieldset").index(current_fs)).removeClass("active");

    //show the previous fieldset
    previous_fs.show(); 
    //hide the current fieldset with style
    current_fs.animate({opacity: 0}, {
        step: function(now, mx) {
            //as the opacity of current_fs reduces to 0 - stored in "now"
            //1. scale previous_fs from 80% to 100%
            scale = 0.8 + (1 - now) * 0.2;
            //2. take current_fs to the right(50%) - from 0%
            left = ((1-now) * 50)+"%";
            //3. increase opacity of previous_fs to 1 as it moves in
            opacity = 1 - now;
            current_fs.css({'left': left});
            previous_fs.css({'transform': 'scale('+scale+')', 'opacity': opacity});
        }, 
        duration: 800, 
        complete: function(){
            current_fs.hide();
            animating = false;
        }, 
        //this comes from the custom easing plugin
        easing: 'easeInOutBack'
    });
});

$(".submit").click(function(){
    return false;
})
</script>

<!-- jQuery -->
<script src="http://thecodeplayer.com/uploads/js/jquery-1.9.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<!-- jQuery easing plugin -->
<script src="http://thecodeplayer.com/uploads/js/jquery.easing.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: Stack Overflow isn't a code generation service. What have you tried, and how has it failed?

Comment: @ChrisHayes I'm not really familiar with JQuery or JS, I was hoping someone could point me in the right direction.

Comment: just assaign `id` for each button. then simply write `js` code to `hide / show` corresponding `fieldset`.

Comment: @CJRamki Hey CJ thanks for the info, could you show me what that piece of JS code would look like?

Comment: @NJay You just want to navigate to Math or science only. right?

Comment: @CJRamki  Yeah, If a user choose "Math" it would lead them to a differing input or fieldset than if they chose "Science".

Comment: Move jqeury reference before to your custom code...!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**FYI:**

I gave a detailed answer. So, please read the answer fully and understand what are all the changes I made in your code.

**Answer in Detail:**

Give Identification for each `fieldset` to work as per your requirement. do like below,

```
<fieldset id="firstField"> <!-- First Step -->
<fieldset id="mathsField"> <!-- Maths -->
<fieldset id="scienceField"> <!-- Science -->
```

Your `js` code is working based on `.next` and `.previous` classes. So, we should put our logic to change that flow. You already assigned name for buttons math and science like below,

```
<input type="button" name="maths" class="next action-button" value="Math" />
<input type="button" name="science" class="next action-button" value="Science" />
```

So, In `$(".next").click(function(){ });` just check **if the clicked button is math or science** by button `name` and set that corresponding `fieldset` DOM to variable `next_fs` like below code,

```
if($(this).attr('name') == 'maths')
    next_fs = $('#mathsField');
if($(this).attr('name') == 'science')
    next_fs = $('#scienceField');
```

and in `$(".previous").click(function(){ });` set `#firstField` DOM to variable `previous_fs` like below code,

```
previous_fs = $('#firstField');
```

SEE THIS JSFIDDLE <kbd>**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/cjramki/bj8pd5op/)**</kbd>